# Browser Context Menu customization?

Tags: browser, overriding, contextmenu

Is there a way to override the "undo" and "select all" in right click context menu of the browser over textarea?

Thank you.

Comment: when you say override, do you mean to remove/disable these items, or change their functionality?

Comment: Preferably change.
You see I have my own "undo" and "select all", the default won't do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit the browser's built-in context menu, but you can disable it and replace it with your own using the `oncontextmenu` event on the `window` object.  I would caution that this is often a bad idea.  Users expect to find the built-in context menu and are often frustrated when it isn't there.

Comment: It's useless to create my own menu since I can't simulate "copy" and "paste", damn security :P

Answer (score 1):

I know you can prevent the whole context menu from opening by registering to the click() event, doing some cross-browser mumbo-jumbo to get wich button was clicked, and then return false if the right one was clicked.

However, I don't think it's possible to modify the context menu itself, at least not using javascript.

I should add that you may want to rethink why you're doing this. This will never be a protection against anything (some try to prevent copying images from their website), as it may simply be disabled by turning javascript off.

UPDATE: Ok, so you don't want to prevent users to do things, bug have them doing things your way. Then, I guess the best thing to do is :

1. Provide users with a toolbar that allow them to do these things (and thus making them use your actions instead of the default one
2. Map the usual keyboard shortcuts to your actions (Ctrl+A, Ctrl+Z, etc...)
3. Replace the right click menu with your own.

You mentionned in another comment that you cannot reproduce copy/paste, which is correct, but you can implement you own clipboard (that will only work for your webapp) if you really have to.

Comment: I'm not trying to prevent people from stealing stuff, come on.
I need to either change or disable "undo" and "select all" because they might and probably will create a mess in my webapp.

Comment: As I said before, there is no way to simulate "copy" and "paste"... And I do want my users to copy/paste from/to my webapp.. :/