# Disable the save option from downloading window? In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, i am trying to disable or remove the save dialog , when user click the download option. Can you help me. Thank you. LIke Do You want to Open or save this file?
in this option i want only Open option not save option.

Comment: Not really .NET, it's client side stuff. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954047/browser-context-menu-customization

Answer (score 0):

**solution 1: Client side javascript**
You can use client side onclick function to disable that button

Code Something like this

> button runat='server' onlick="this.enabled = false;return true;"

this condition would make your save execute and also disable the button.

**solution2: Server side**
You can use the update panel and place your button inside it.

Next you can on server button click method disable that button or hide it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove the option "open" in download dialog box, but i am not able to disable the "save" option. Is it is possible to disable the save option in downloading dialog box.
My code like this.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(Filename));
        Response.AddHeader("X-Download-Options", "noopen");
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```